# How to call a function when clicked a kivy button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm pretty new to kivy. I want to call a function in the App class. But it gives an error.
The error is "on_press: app.hello()
 TypeError: hello() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

.kv file code

```
            Button:
            id: add_income_btn
            size_hint: (.05, .2)
            pos: (393, 302)
            background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
            text: "+"
            font_size:'20sp'
            on_press: app.hello()
```

.py file code

```
Builder.load_file("test1.kv")
class Money_Manager(App,TabbedPanel): 
    def hello():
        print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods of an instantiated Class in Python need a `self` argument (the current Class instance).
So you must use:

```py
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One :

```
on_press: app.hello
```

instead of

```
on_press: app.hello()
```